# Meteor js callback not working

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, callback

I set up a callback function inside my Meteor async method to be called on "readable" event. But the callback is not being called when the on."readable" is being fired (I know it's being fired from the console.log I set up).

Am I missing something here? I've been at it for a few hours now trying a few different things!

```
Meteor.startup(() => {

  Meteor.call("getfeed", function(feedloader) {
    //I get: TypeError: undefined is not a function]
    console.log(feedloader);
  });

});

Meteor.methods({

  getfeed: function(callb) {

    var req = request('http://feeds.feedburner.com/Techcrunch');
    var feedparser = new FeedParser();
    testing = [];

    //........a bunch of functions........

    feedparser.on('readable', function() {

      var stream = this
        , meta = this.meta
        , item;

      while (item = stream.read()) 
      {
        //I'm pushing the results into testing var
        testing.push(item);
      }

      //From the logs I can see that this is called 12 times
      //but the callback's not firing!!!

      console.log(testing.length);
      callb(testing);

    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor methods are not asynchronous functions in the sense that they do not get the callback argument even though you pass it when you "call" a method. Instead each method is executed within a `Fiber` which is another flavor of dealing with asynchronous code.

Fortunately, Meteor has a nice helper that allows you to mix both styles. What you need to do is wrap the "pure" asynchronous part of your method code with `Meteor.wrapAsync`. This structure should look more or less like this:

```
Meteor.methods({

  getfeed: function() {
    var wrapped = Meteor.wrapAsync(function (callb) {

      var feedparser = new FeedParser();
      testing = [];

      // ...

      feedparser.on('readable', function() {
        // probably the same code you have, but without "callb()"
      });

      feedparser.on('end', function () {
        // NOTE: No error here, so the first argument must be null.
        callb(null, testing);
      })
    });

    // NOTE: Finally, call the wrapped function
    return wrapped();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, the problem here is that I dont have an 'end' event. The 'readable' event here is repeatedly called until it stops and I dont know when itll stop! so is there a way I can keep the 'testing' variable in sync with a variable?

Comment: Sorry my bad. There is an end event. Missed that!

Comment: And yeah it must be return wrapped(); instead of just wrapped();